# What terminal commands are new or updated in Mountain Lion?

Tags: terminal, macos, command-line

Where can I find a list of new or updated terminal commands or features for Mountain Lion?

Lacking any list, does anyone have a sugguestion on how to generate that list?  (some combination of ls & diff)

Comment: It might also be interesting to compare the man pages to search for new options. `defaults` has an `-app` flag for specifying an application name instead of a bundle identifier. I'm not sure if it was added in 10.8 or 10.7, but `open` has an `-F` flag that opens applications fresh or without restoring windows.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

AD user @patrix did a great AD blog post on new terminal commands in Mountain Lion. You can find it here: http://apple.blogoverflow.com/2012/07/interesting-new-unix-commandsbinaries-in-os-x-mountain-lion/

Answer (score 5):

The answer is in the following post:

[New Unix commands in ML](http://apple.blogoverflow.com/2012/07/interesting-new-unix-commandsbinaries-in-os-x-mountain-lion/)